# background images path not working in CSS

Tags: css

Relative path not working in CSS  while it's correct

```
{ width: 64px; background: url(../images/abc/xyz/bottom-navigation.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; }
```

**Firebug giving this error**

[image]

Folder path
[image]

Comment: you have to give us more info if you expect us to help you

Comment: Is the image loading in firebug's net panel? What does the DOM look like?

Comment: what's the full absolute path to both your stylesheet and the image (use example.com for your domain if concerned about privacy)

Comment: For one thing, I notice in your code sample it's a `.jpg` file, while in the screenshot it appears to be an entirely different `.gif` file.

Comment: but  file name is different too. image i  added for example

Comment: Show your folder structure, like this: http://jguard.sourceforge.net/mvnsite/docbook/WTP_Project_Folder_Structure.png

Comment: Why don't you just show the full folder structure with real image names and a full css class? We can't solve the problem if we can't see it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In CSS the path is relative to the stylesheet, so make sure you have that correct. Based on the code you posted, your stylesheet would need to be in a folder (e.g. `css`) and that folder would be at the same directory level as `images`.

The alternative and generally better option is to use a path that's relative to your domain. So if the images folder is in the root, you would do use `url("/images/abc/xyz/bottom-navigation.jpg")` (note, it's good practice to put quotes around filenames in CSS).

The other possibility is that there is some kind of problem loading the image. In Firebug you should be able to right click the URL and open the image. Do this and make sure it loads and is showing the correct path.

Comment: @Jitendra, try opening the image through Firebug - does the image load? Also, a live example would be handy if possible.

Comment: @Jitendra, what was the problem? It would be helpful to mention how you actually solved the problem for others' future reference.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - The problem was instead of `../images/abc/xyz/bottom-navigation.jpg` , `../../../images/abc/xyz/bottom-navigation.jpg` was required

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem,and figured it out after some time.
Basically relative url's for background was not working if the image was in level-up directories from your current directory.
It has to be in same or sub directory.
This worked for me.

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your server configurations.