# CSS background-image not loading, but loads after I inspect it

Tags: html, css

In one of my websites, I am using css `background-image` property to set the background for different sections. All the sections load their background images properly except for the contact section.

When I try to inspect it, the inspector shows that the background image could not be loaded in the tool tip. But when I try to open the image in a new tab, I can see the image perfectly, After I do this, when I do a refresh of the page, I am able to see the background image for that section correctly now. I inspected the Network tab and don't even find the image file being called. However, after opening the image in a new tab and then inspecting the network tab shows the image.

Error when I inspect before trying to open the image in a new tab:

[image]

My site can be viewed [here](http://www.srsconstructions.com). The error happens in the Contact Section and can be viewed [here](http://srsconstructions.com/#contact)

Please help me with this strange error.

Comment: Which background are you talking about? The bricks? It loaded fine on my side.

Comment: Yes, the bricks. That's strange. Can you try loading that in a private window ?

Comment: Just did too and worked fine still. Perhaps you just need to empty your cache?

Comment: I've actually checked in a number of different systems and mobile and still couldn't see the image :(

Comment: I tried with Firefox and Chrome in Windows 10

Comment: It's working fine for me too, on chrome mobile.

Comment: On Chrome, Mac. Worked fine. Even in incognito.

Comment: Thanks everyone for testing. I still don't know why this error happens in all of my systems. Maybe it is some cache issue or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are getting this error in console:

[image]

The HTTP 409 Conflict response status code indicates a request conflict with current state of the server

Your Image Path:

[image]

The alternative and generally better option is to use a path that's relative to your domain, You should pass your image:

[image]

Please see this post:
[background images path not working in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802692/background-images-path-not-working-in-css)

Comment: Oh I did not see that. Can you please explain why a request conflict would occur ?

Comment: Image path. Notice the slash that made the difference. The level of the folder was the reason why sometimes you could not load the image.